# how to get the string from user input in alert textfield

Tags: ios, swift

i am trying to get a string from user input textfield in an alert like that, but I always get nil value. the code i use to show that alert textfield is like this

```
 @IBAction func addButtonPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        // show an alert to show up a quick textfield


        var textField = UITextField()
        let itemTitle = textField.text!

        print("the title is \(itemTitle) ....")


        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Add Item to your to do list", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let addItemAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Add item", style: .default) { (action) in
            // after user click "add item", the new item will be displayed to table view

            let newItem = Item()
            newItem.title = itemTitle


            self.itemArray.append(newItem)
            self.saveItems()


        }


        alert.addTextField { (alertTextfield) in
            alertTextfield.placeholder = "Create a new item"
            textField = alertTextfield
            // store a data from user to 'textField' variable, so it can be accessed in closure at 'addItemAction'
        }



        alert.addAction(addItemAction)
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```

**My UI**

[image]

I am trying to print the `itemTitle`, but i never get the string from the user. like this

**Output**

[image]

what went wrong in here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will get that once user pressed `Add item` not before that where you are trying to print it.

check below code:

```
let addItemAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Add item", style: .default) { (action) in

    // after user click "add item", the new item will be displayed to table view
    print(textField.text)  //Here you will get user text.

    let newItem = Item()
    newItem.title = textField.text //add it here
    self.itemArray.append(newItem)
    self.saveItems()   
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
   /// define alert controller 
  let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert Title",
                          message: "Alert message",
                          preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

 /// add OK Action
  let ok = UIAlertAction(title: "OK",
                   style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) { (action: UIAlertAction) in

    /// get the textfield instance form textFields array

                    if let alertTextField = alert.textFields?.first, alertTextField.text != nil {

                        print("And the text is... \(alertTextField.text!)!")

                    }


  }

     /// add CANCEL Action

   let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel",
                       style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel,
                       handler: nil)

    /// add first textfeild to the alertController
    alert.addTextField { (textField: UITextField) in

    /// configure textfeild with properties like placeholder and textColor
    textField.placeholder = "Text here"

 }

/// add actions to the alertController

alert.addAction(ok)
alert.addAction(cancel)

/// present alertController in current viewController

self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Answers are more helpful with an explanation of the problem and the solution, instead of a "try this" code dump only.

Comment: OK , I will add comments

Answer (score 2):

You have to get the text from textField when `Add Item` is pressed.

Change this

```
newItem.title = itemTitle
```

to

```
newItem.title = textField.text
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all, `let itemTitle = textField.text!` will make the itemTitle only assigned once and it will contain empty string as your `textField` doesn't have any value yet, thats why when you printed it out, it does not return any string.

if you want a messy way to do it, you could keep your code but delete

```
let itemTitle = textField.text!
```

and do what @Bilal said